# Difference in timings from NgOnInit/NgAfterViewInit and subscription of a different observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have an API call to get the response from WebAPI in the ngOnInit method. I am also tracking the response timings of all the API calls in the interceptor. This tracking ends when the response is received using "tap" of rxjs.

```
.pipe(tap((data) => {}));
```

I also have the same kind of tracking on WebAPI for response timings.
From the dev-tools, network call is completed in around 70/100 ms, almost the same timing is tracked by the tracking on the WebAPI side. But the interceptor is tracking around 1200 ms, please note that there is no additional logic in the map.

This same call took only around 150/200 ms when added in the subscribe method of another observable to load some data. Please note that this second observable is triggered by another component based on the logic in NgAfterViewInit.

I Tried moving the calls from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit but the same behavior.

I tried to read the documentation of RxJS, Lifecycle hook to find if there is anything that could be blocking to trigger tap when API is called while UI is being rendered.

Any suggestions on finding out the difference in these timings would help.

Update: Not posting the exact code but this should give you the idea, it does not have any additional logic which is not mentioned in here.

The below code is in the ngOnInit method.

```
this.service.getSomeData().subscribe(data => {
  this.somevariable = data;
});
```

In the service below code is present.

```
public getSomeData(): Observable<SomeType> {
  this.tracking.start("getSomeData");
  return this.httpClient.get<SomeType>(this.apiHostPathUrl).pipe(
    tap(_ => { this.tracking.end("getSomeData"); })).map(item => {
      item.someProperty = <some logic here to change the value>;
      return item;
    });
}
```

Tracking service uses Performance Timing API (https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html) to mark the start and end of the transaction once the response is received. I had moved the tracking from intercepter to individual service call for this case but in INTERCEPTOR also I am using the tap to end the tracking.

Comment: Could you please add your interceptor code, and other relevant parts? (service method that you call, ngOnInit/ngAfterViewInit, etc)

Comment: @Guillaume: Thanks for the response. Question updated.